# Does ConfigureAwait(false) here achieve anything

Tags: c#, task

If in a library I have this

```
public async DoSomething()
{
   await Foo();
}
```

I then call this like `lib.DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Would that give me the same benefit as if the library had originally had

```
public async DoSomething()
{
   await Foo().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: You should ask whether `async/await` achieves anything here. If the method doesn't do anything after `Foo(), `async/await` only adds overhead. Just return the Task.  `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is actually a very bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not give you the same benefit. If you have:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    await Foo();
}
```

And then do

```
lib.DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

From, for example, UI thread in WPF application - you will deadlock. Before `await Foo()` you were on UI thread (there was WPF-specific `SynchronizationContext.Current`) and after await you will try to return back to UI thread. UI thread is blocked on `GetResult()` so that will result in deadlock. Actually, `ConfigureAwait(false)` is useless here.

If on the other hand you have

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
   await Foo().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And the do

```
lib.DoSomething().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

No deadlock will happen, because `ConfigureAwait(false)` tells specifically to not "continue on captured context", so to not return back to `SynchronizationContext` (UI thread in this case).

Comment: Would this be a workaround if we cannot control the fact the library doesn't have ConfigureAwait(false)?

            var syncCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

            try
            {
                lib.DoSomething().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            finally
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);
            }

Comment: @Jon well I suppose so, but I'd use something like `Task.Run(DoSomething).Wait();` in that case. Though in reality I'd never block on async code from UI thread anyway, never was in situation where it was absolutely necessary.

Comment: If you do a Task.Run.Wait() you don't get the result back though?

Comment: @Jon well I assumed it's `void` (`Task`) async method. If not then sure - `Task.Run(DoSomething).Result` should do.